# Qlik Sense URL - Javascript - .Net

Tags: javascript, qlikview, qliksense

I am making a Qlik sense application in .Net using the Single Configurator.
I have an issue with urls that are not generated correctly.

```
<a ng-if="cell.representation === 'url' && ( !selections.active && interactive )" qva-activate="openUrl(cell.url)" ng-attr-title="{{cell.url}}" class="ng-scope ng-binding" title="http://xxx.xx/xx/xxx/xxx/1234">Sporingsside</a>
```

As you can see from the auto-generated HTML above, the href is missing. The URL is displayed in the title...

Furthermore, it is set to be a URL in the Qlik sense app itself.

Does anyone have a solution to this, or have encountered the same problem? Or maybe even know if there is possible to change the qlik.js resource?